# Blender 2.8 : Black faces when baking ambient occlusion

Tags: texture-baking, ambient-occlusion

I have a high poly crater that I'd want to make it into a low poly object.

[image]

This is my low poly model for the crater.

[image]

When I try to bake the ambient occlusion, there are solid black faces popping on my uv map.[image]

This is the result:

[image]

I've tried many things but without success... How do you get rid of those black faces?

Comment: make sure, that you haven't hidden objects in your scene.

Comment: I did hide some objects, but I don't want these to interact with the ambient occlusion. Is this a problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, hidden object may affects on baking. To solve this issue, do following. Enable render and viewport toggles in Outliner in Filter menu:

[image]

then make your object invisible in render and viewport, by pressing on camera and monitor icons:

[image]